# How do I configure WCF on the server side to only allow Kerberos?

Tags: .net, wcf, kerberos

The title pretty much says it all, I'd like to configure my WCF service so that users can only use Kerberos to authenticate, not NTLM (for debugging purposes). Is there any way to do it?

On the client side it's apparently done by setting clientCredentials/windows/@allowNtlm="false" but there seems to be no equivalent property for the server.

My config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="rest">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Xml" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false" faultExceptionEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="MyService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="rss" contract="MyProject.IMyService" behaviorConfiguration="rest" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/MyProject/MyService/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="rss">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: According to this Windows is Kerberos. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729700.aspx

Comment: ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity.AuthenticationType is however "NTLM" in this case so I presume the authentication falls back to NTLM instead of failing.

Comment: What have you tried?  Why would you set AuthenticationType to "NTLM" when you don't want "NTLM"?

Comment: I'm not setting AuthenticationType, I have a debug WCF operation where I print the context as XML and that's where I see the value. I added my config to the question.

Comment: I would try Message or Transport in the mode.  Not sure it would fix it but what I would try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can achieve this, hosting your service in `IIS` - you can specify enabled authentification providers, rightclicking on `'Windows Authentification'` item in `Authentification settings` of `IIS` manager. Simply turn off/on needed providers.

Comment: Is there a way to do it for a self-hosted service?

Comment: I didnt find any info 'bout it